# MySQL/PHP: If the table user is empty, how to generate default admin account

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to add a function to my project that will automatically generate a default username and password value for an admin to log in to the system if the table for the admin user in my SQL database is empty. Is there anyone who knows how to do it?

Comment: You woudl have to login using the `root` account, which may or may not have a password

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why a default admin user can not be added using a script. A table function requires some type of action Insert, Update, or Delete to happen before it will execute.
If there is a front end program you could have it call a stored proc that looks if the table is empty and if so then insert a default username and password or have the program redirect to a screen so the user can add the username and password they want as the first admin account.
Depending on the exact need there are several ways to accomplish what you are needing but a function will not work for what you are currently asking.

This will of course require the database connection to use a default account that has the proper permissions. I am assuming that you are wanting to add admins for the program to a table and not database access.